jq and vm fail to parse json
I am working on parsing data returned from a cast call. I have tried using jq with vm.ffi  and also vm.parseJson. Both methods fail without any obvious error.
I need the status field in the top level of the json blob and also the transactionHash in the logs.
And idea how to fix this?
My contract:
function mint(string calldata _tokenAddress, uint256 _amount) public returns (string memory, string memory){
        console.log("Minting ", _amount, "tokens");
        // cast send "$XToken" "mint(uint256)" 100000088840000000000667 --rpc-url "$rpc_url" --from "$WALLET_ADDRESS" --private-key "$PRIVATE_KEY"
        string[] memory inputs = new string[](12);
        inputs[0] = "cast";
        inputs[1] = "send";
        inputs[2] = _tokenAddress;
        inputs[3] = "mint(uint256)";
        inputs[4] = vm.toString(_amount);
        inputs[5] = "--json";
        inputs[6] = "--rpc-url";
        inputs[7] = vm.envString("SEPOLIA_HTTP_RPC_URL");
        inputs[8] = "--from";
        inputs[9] = vm.envString("WALLET_ADDRESS");
        inputs[10] = "--private-key";
        inputs[11] = vm.envString("PRIVATE_KEY");

        bytes memory result = vm.ffi(inputs);
        console.log("Cast result",string(result));

        if (0 == result.length) {
            console.log("Error: cast call returned empty result");
            revert("Error: cast call returned empty result");
        }

        string memory resultString = string(result);
        string memory resultKey = ".status";//execution stops if no dot in the resultKey
        bytes memory statusBytes = vm.parseJson(resultString, resultKey);

        // Convert `statusBytes` to a readable string
        string memory statusString = string(abi.encodePacked(statusBytes));
        console.log("statusString1: ", statusString);

        console.log("trying with jq below");
        // Parse the status field using jq
        string[] memory jqStatusCmd = new string[](4);
        jqStatusCmd[0] = "jq";
        jqStatusCmd[1] = "-r";
        jqStatusCmd[2] = ".status";
        jqStatusCmd[3] = resultString;
        statusBytes = vm.ffi(jqStatusCmd);
        console.log("statusBytes");
        console.logBytes(statusBytes);
        console.log("StatusString2:", string(statusBytes));

        string[] memory jqTxHashCmd = new string[](4);
        jqTxHashCmd[0] = "jq";
        jqTxHashCmd[1] = "-r";
        jqTxHashCmd[2] = "transactionHash";
        jqTxHashCmd[3] = resultString;
        statusString = abi.decode(statusBytes, (string));//<---fails here


        // Use ffi to directly parse transactionHash
        bytes memory txHashBytes = vm.ffi(jqTxHashCmd);
        string memory txHashString = abi.decode(txHashBytes, (string));

        // Log the status and transactionHash as strings
        console.log("Transaction Status: ", statusString);
        console.log("Transaction Hash: ", txHashString);

        return(txHashString,statusString);
}

The logs look like:
Logs:
  Owner Address: 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693
  Function Test ExecuteArbitrage
  Minting  1000000000000000000 tokens
  Cast result {"status":"0x1","cumulativeGasUsed":"0xb279aa","logs":[{"address":"0xbc35bd49d5de2929522e5cc3f40460d74d24c24c","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x000000000000000000000000b04d6a4949fa623629e0ed6bd4ecb78a8c847693"],"data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000","blockHash":"0x70d79a4e02fa4f9d626961705752e90c561b4e6ecefbd184b48e5051b0aab964","blockNumber":"0x6bd1d9","transactionHash":"0xa6d1c9e0d6f9d451b486992a3b9b684d9783daf5c1badc651229df4ffb209692","transactionIndex":"0x2e","logIndex":"0x37","removed":false},{"address":"0xbc35bd49d5de2929522e5cc3f40460d74d24c24c","topics":["0xb9203d657e9c0ec8274c818292ab0f58b04e1970050716891770eb1bab5d655e"],"data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000000000000000000000000000b04d6a4949fa623629e0ed6bd4ecb78a8c847693","blockHash":"0x70d79a4e02fa4f9d626961705752e90c561b4e6ecefbd184b48e5051b0aab964","blockNumber":"0x6bd1d9","transactionHash":"0xa6d1c9e0d6f9d451b486992a3b9b684d9783daf5c1badc651229df4ffb209692","transactionIndex":"0x2e","logIndex":"0x38","removed":false}],"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000008400000000000000000000000000000000000000008008000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000020000000000000000000800000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000","type":"0x2","transactionHash":"0xa6d1c9e0d6f9d451b486992a3b9b684d9783daf5c1badc651229df4ffb209692","transactionIndex":"0x2e","blockHash":"0x70d79a4e02fa4f9d626961705752e90c561b4e6ecefbd184b48e5051b0aab964","blockNumber":"0x6bd1d9","gasUsed":"0x9160","effectiveGasPrice":"0x995876a","from":"0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ed6bd4ecb78a8c847693","to":"0xbc35bd49d5de2929522e5cc3f40460d74d24c24c","contractAddress":null}
  statusString1:   
  trying with jq below
  statusBytes
  0x
  StatusString2: 

My foundry.toml looks like
[profile.default]
src = "src"
out = "out"
libs = ["lib"]
optimizer = false
via_ir = false
debug = true  # Enable debug information
solc = "0.8.26"  # Use the version compatible with your contracts
#rpc_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
rpc_url = "${SEPOLIA_HTTP_RPC_URL}"
etherscan_api_key = "${ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}"
private_key = "${PRIVATE_KEY}"
auto_detect_remappings = true # recursive auto-detection of remappings
remappings = []
broadcast = 'broadcast'
show_progress = true
build_info = true
ffi = true
fs_permissions = [
    { access = "read", path = "./broadcast" },
    { access = "read", path = "./reports" },
]

# See more config options https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/blob/master/crates/config/README.md#all-options

Later on I came up with this solution, it appears to be working for this example.
function mint(string calldata _tokenAddress, uint256 _amount) public returns (string memory, string memory){
        console.log("Minting ", _amount, "tokens");
        // cast send "$XToken" "mint(uint256)" 100000088840000000000667 --rpc-url "$rpc_url" --from "$WALLET_ADDRESS" --private-key "$PRIVATE_KEY"
        string[] memory inputs = new string[](12);
        inputs[0] = "cast";
        inputs[1] = "send";
        inputs[2] = _tokenAddress;
        inputs[3] = "mint(uint256)";
        inputs[4] = vm.toString(_amount);
        inputs[5] = "--json";
        inputs[6] = "--rpc-url";
        inputs[7] = vm.envString("SEPOLIA_HTTP_RPC_URL");
        inputs[8] = "--from";
        inputs[9] = vm.envString("WALLET_ADDRESS");
        inputs[10] = "--private-key";
        inputs[11] = vm.envString("PRIVATE_KEY");

        bytes memory result = vm.ffi(inputs);
        if (0 == result.length) {
            console.log("Error: cast call returned empty result");
            revert("Error: cast call returned empty result");
        }
        string memory json = string(result);

        string memory statusField = '"status":"';
        uint statusFieldLength = bytes(statusField).length;
        string memory status = parseField(json, '"status":"', statusFieldLength);

        string memory transactionHashField = '"transactionHash":"';
        uint transactionHashLength = bytes(transactionHashField).length;
        string memory transactionHash = parseField(json, '"transactionHash":"', transactionHashLength);

        return (transactionHash,status);
    }


    function parseField(string memory json, string memory field, uint fieldLength) internal pure returns (string memory value) {
        bytes memory jsonBytes = bytes(json);
        uint256 statusStart = findIndexOfSubstring(jsonBytes, field, 0) + fieldLength;
        uint256 statusEnd = findIndexOfSubstring(jsonBytes, '"', statusStart);
        value = extractSubstring(json, statusStart, statusEnd);
    }

    // Helper function to find the position of a substring starting from a specified index
    function findIndexOfSubstring(bytes memory data, string memory substring, uint256 startIndex)
    internal
    pure
    returns (uint256)
    {
        bytes memory subBytes = bytes(substring);
        uint256 dataLength = data.length;
        uint256 subLength = subBytes.length;

        if (subLength == 0 || dataLength < subLength || startIndex >= dataLength) {
            revert("Invalid substring or start index");
        }

        for (uint256 i = startIndex; i <= dataLength - subLength; i++) {
            bool matchFound = true;
            for (uint256 j = 0; j < subLength; j++) {
                if (data[i + j] != subBytes[j]) {
                    matchFound = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (matchFound) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        revert("Substring not found");
    }

    // Helper function to extract a substring from a string given start and end indices
    function extractSubstring(string memory str, uint256 start, uint256 end)
    internal
    pure
    returns (string memory)
    {
        bytes memory strBytes = bytes(str);
        require(end <= strBytes.length, "Invalid end position");
        bytes memory result = new bytes(end - start);
        for (uint256 i = start; i < end; i++) {
            result[i - start] = strBytes[i];
        }
        return string(result);
    }


You can see in the Foundry docs, that vm.ffi() calls an arbitrary command only if ffi is enabled.
You can enable the same by making its value as true in the foundry.toml file, by adding this line:
ffi = true


NOTE: Please refer to the ffi description, which states:

It is generally advised to use this cheat code as a last resort, and
to not enable it by default, as anyone who can change the tests of a
project will be able to execute arbitrary commands on devices that run
the tests.

So, I would highly recommend you to avoid using that in production.

EDIT: Provided that you've already added ffi = true in your foundry.toml file.
Instead of jq and vm.parseJson, you can import and use the stdJson library to achieve the JSON parsing.
import {stdJson} from "forge-std/StdJson.sol";

And, add the using for directive for the same in the starting of your contract/script/test code, like:
using stdJson for string;

Like:
contract MyTest {
    using stdJson for string;
    // Rest of the code
}

Then, you can call the parseRaw function using your result JSON string and filter out the required key-value pairs and decode them as per the requirement, like:
bytes memory status = result.parseRaw(".status");

uint256[] memory values = abi.decode(status, (uint256[]));

uint256 statusInt = values[0];
statusInt = statusInt == 0 ? 0 : statusInt >> (256 - 8); // Right shift to remove padding

console.log("Status:", toHexString(statusInt));

bytes memory transactionHash = result.parseRaw(".transactionHash");

console.log("Transaction Hash:", vm.toString(transactionHash));

NOTE: toHexString is the utility function that I'm using to convert the uint256 value to its hex-representation, and I've referenced it from this answer given by @Ismael.
function toHexDigit(uint8 d) internal pure returns (bytes1) {
    if (0 <= d && d <= 9) {
        return bytes1(uint8(bytes1("0")) + d);
    } else if (10 <= uint8(d) && uint8(d) <= 15) {
        return bytes1(uint8(bytes1("a")) + d - 10);
    }
    revert();
}

function toHexString(uint256 a) public pure returns (string memory) {
    uint256 count = 0;
    uint256 b = a;
    while (b != 0) {
        count++;
        b /= 16;
    }
    bytes memory res = new bytes(count);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        b = a % 16;
        res[count - i - 1] = toHexDigit(uint8(b));
        a /= 16;
    }
    return string(abi.encodePacked("0x", string(res)));
}

Instead of using toHexString function, you can also retain and show the statusInt value as it is, because the Ethereum Transaction Types can be categorized on the basis of unsigned-integer values too, like 0, 1, 2, along with their hex-representations like 0x0, 0x1, 0x2 respectively.
P.S., I've created this example gist utilizing the same code and the hardcoded JSON string for your reference.

Please see my edits, the foundry.toml has been updated.

@pigfox, I've edited my answer. Please check.
